# How to get mulitple elements working with jQuerys no.Conflict(); string

Tags: javascript, jquery, conflict

I have 4 elements, a Date Picker, Sliding Panel, News Ticker and a JQ Dock. 3 out of the four are working but the one that isn't only works with the min jQuery library. For example, the scripts below all work with this script source.

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function($) {

        // eBusiness Card   

        $('#panelHandle').hover(function() {
            $('#sidePanel').stop(true, false).animate({
                'left': '2px'
            }, 900);
        }, function() {
            jQuery.noConflict();
        });

        $('#sidePanel').hover(function() {
            jQuery.noConflict();
        }, function() {

            jQuery.noConflict();
            jQuery('#sidePanel').animate({
                left: '-223px'
            }, 800);

            }); 
        });

        // Opening Tabbed Content

        // run the jquery ui plugin
        $('.CardHolder > div > a').tabs();

        // grab the url
        var url = document.aboutusCoaches.html;
        // grab the value of the hash
        var hashValue = url.substring(url.indexOf('#')).replace('#', '');

        // check to make sure it is a number
        if (!isNaN(hashValue)) {
            // set the active tab
            $('.ProfileMenu > ul > li > a').tabs("option", "selected", hashValue);
        }               



</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function () {

  $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
      inline:true,
      dateFormat: "d MM yy",
      showOn: "both",
      buttonImage: "Images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Calendar",
      minDate: new Date(2013, 10, 18),
      maxDate: new Date(2013, 10, 21),
      defaultDate: "today",
      numberOfMonths: 1,

  });

  $("#datepicker2").datepicker({
      inline:true,
      dateFormat: "d MM yy",
      showOn: "both",
      buttonImage: "Images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Calendar",
      minDate: new Date(2013, 10, 26),
      maxDate: new Date(2013, 10, 29),
      defaultDate: "today",
      numberOfMonths: 1,

  });

});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript"><!-- Banner Ticker -->

  jQuery(function(){
      $('#newsticker-container').newsTicker();      
    });

</script><!-- Banner Ticker End -->
```

Then the jqDock only works with this min script source

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            var jqDockOpts = {align: 'right', duration: 200, labels: 'tc', size: 55, distance: 85};
            $('#jqDock').jqDock(jqDockOpts);
        });

</script>
```

Also I should point out that all the elements work using the min script except the datepicker ( which uses the full library ). I saw a solution that talks about jQuery no.conflict(); - which I tried and still no joy. Should I be placing all elements inside 1 script tag with the no conflict coming first? This is probably simple for the expert, which I'm not so please go easy on me :).

Comment: `noConflict()` can be used like this. `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();` then you use `$j` instead of `$` for jQuery calls.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have tried it and the problem still persists. I'll look into the suggestion made by Mike W and see if a solution turns up

Answer (score 0):

You have two very differet versions of jQuery here. Some of the functions present in jQuery 1.3.2 have been deprecated for a long time, and removed in 1.9.1. Similarly, new functions have been added that don't exist in 1.3.2.

jQuery.noConflict is unlikely to help since bothe versions will use the global jQuery object. Which version you get will depend on the order you load them in.

I don't know what jqDock does, but you'd be well advised to seek a later version that uses current jQuery, or a different module that does the same job.